# Remove element from array of objects if the element will be inserted again

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

First of all hello!

I got an array of objects like this in JS:

```
[{name: "pepe", id: "#34"}{name: "juan", id: "#23"}]
```

And i want remove an object from the array if the user tries to insert the item again.

**Example**

Original array:

```
[{name: "pepe", id: "#34"}{name: "juan", id: "#23"}]
```

User clicks to add pepe again. Result:

```
[{name: "juan", id: "#23"}]
```

If someone could help me it will be great!

Comment: How does the user tries to insert ?

Comment: Clicking on a table

Comment: So check to see if it is there brfore inserting and if it is, remove it.... You want `find()`

Comment: Please, explain yourself in a better manner

Answer (score 1):

You have to find the position of the element by using :

```
index = array_name.findIndex(obj => obj.name === "pepe");
```

After that, you can use

```
array_name.splice(index, 1);
```

Before using this function, you need to check if the index is not -1.
If you get it, it means the object is not in your list and you should not execute the function. Otherwise, you will get an error.

Comment: Make sure it's not `-1` before splicing or will remove unwanted item from end of array

Comment: Yes, sorry. I forgot to explain the -1. If the object is not in your list, the index will be -1. Thanks charlietf. :)l

Comment: I tried `var index = checkedMolsTable.findIndex(obj => checkedMolsTable.iky === iky);
                    if (index === -1) {
                        checkedMolsTable.splice(index, 1);
                    } else {
                        for (var mol in filteredDataSet) {  
                            if (filteredDataSet[mol].iky === iky) { 
                                checkedMolsTable.push(filteredDataSet[mol]);
                            }
                        }
                    }` But index is always -1 @charlietfl

Comment: @MarcSerretiGarcia `checkedMolsTable.iky === iky` should be `obj.iky === iky`

Comment: @charlietfl. True, but the problem persists, always -1

Comment: @MarcSerretiGarcia Without some sample data and knowing what `iky` is it's hard to help. Create a demo that reproduces problem